# How to remove word from li using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to replace `Event Date:` word using CSS and without the help of jQuery.

```html
<ul class="event-custom-price">
  <li>Event Date:
    <p>Tue, 25 Jun 2019 02:14 AM - Tue, 25 Jun 2019 03:14 AM</p>
  </li>
  <li>Event Location:</li>
  <li>Teal Moonlight x 1: <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"> <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>3</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello this is my code, I want to replace Event Date word from li tag only using css not Jquery please help me

Comment: You can't remove any node of DOM using CSS .

Comment: first duplicate: how to hide content. Second duplicate: how to add new content

Answer (score 0):

set Tagname for that "event date" tag and apply below css

```
.Tagname:before {
  content: "New Word";
}
```

Comment: This is wordpress plugin I cant hack

Comment: Okay.Then use tagname.

Comment: Can you share code

Comment: like this,  if you want to change <p> tag then use like this p:before { content:"new text"}